# Windows equivalent for SIGPROF

Tags: windows, winapi, signals

I want to set a timer that interrupts any of the currently running threads periodically and executes my custom handler **on that thread**.

I need this in order to sample stack traces with a special API in the JVM that is safe for signal handlers.

On Linux, I can use a SIGPROF signal handler. Is there an equivalent way of doing this on Windows?

Comment: I don't know what options Microsoft provides for doing this, but I know [the Go programming language runtime currently uses a dedicated thread and waitable timers to fake it](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/68ac1f774624faf99e7f6ec6592acb50f23b7874/src/runtime/os_windows.go#L667-L733); your mileage may vary.

Comment: Windows does not permit threads to be interrupted from the outside in this way.  I don't know whether the JVM provides any way to interrupt *its* threads.  If it's any help, Windows *does* allow you to capture stack traces for a given thread using the Debug Help Library.

Comment: Do you want to interrupt Java threads or Windows threads? For Java threads you'd have to look into the hosting environment. For native Windows threads, the [Debugger Engine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540534.aspx) may be helpful.